# What do you call semantic text features?

Tags: structure

## The problem

I've been trying to find a complete list of text features. Things like words, paragraphs, headings, links, bold, italics, lists, tables, quotes, captions, images, indexes, glossaries, labels,  etc.

When I search for "text features" on Google or ChatGPT I get a list of features that mix semantic elements like the ones above, with typographical ones (hyphenation, ligatures, special characters, etc) and stylistic ones (color, contrast, shadow, indentation, alignment, indentation, etc).

#### The questions

Is my distinction and categorization of semantic (headings, paragraphs, links, bold, italics, lists, tables, quotes, captions, images, indexes, glossaries, labels, etc), typographical (hyphenation, ligatures, special characters, etc), and stylistic (thickness, color, contrast, shadow, alignment, indentation, etc) elements correct?

What should I search for to get a complete list of the building blocks of text structure?

#### Why I'm researching this

I'm building a [UI library for React](https://andrecasal.com/ui). I want this library to treat typography with consideration.

#### What I've tried

I've tried the following search terms:

- commonalities between paragraphs, headings, links, bold, italics, lists, tables, quotes
- text features
- complete list of text features
- structural features of text
- building blocks of text
- complete list of structural features of written communication
- building blocks of written communication
- elements of text
- structural elements of written communication
- elements of typography
- semantic elements of typography
- structural elements of typography
- ...and many other variations

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about writing. You can find lists of text features in books on text linguistics.

Comment: How is knowing about the building blocks of text not about writing?

Comment: You write: "I'm building a UI library for React." That is not a writing problem. I also cannot imagine a writing problem where compiling a "complete list of text features" would be the solution. Writing doesn't work that way. And many of the features you mention are irrelevant to writers and fall in the domain of book design.

Comment: Why are you picking on me Ben? Knowing about the building blocks of text is obviously about writing. The reason why I'd like to know about them is inconsequential.

Comment: Your assessment that what you ask about are the *building blocks* of text is wrong. Texts aren't *built* from those elements like a Lego house is built from Lego blocks. Texts are built from motifs, characters, goals, stakes, adversaries, settings, and plot elements. Or, in the case of non-fiction, from ideas, arguments, hypotheses, research findings, conclusions etc. What you ask about are means to structure a printed text visually to facilitate reading, but not elements of which texts are constructed while they are being written.

Comment: Good morning Ben, thank you, that makes sense and is useful  Is there an umbrella term or discipline for the "visual structure of printed text"? This, "text linguistics" and other variations haven't yielded any results and I'm having a hard time finding out what category this falls into and what keywords I could use to find it. I'm also not entirely in agreement with the assumption that this is purely a visual or design concern: the visual structure of printed text does change the text itself, just think of block quotes, lists or tables. Please correct me if I'm wrong 

Comment: Consider "Organisational Features". This is the term used in the Functional Skills English Writing curriculum.

Comment: Thanks Karl, I'll give that a try 